# Wordpress add page(s) with DML?

Tags: wordpress

I'm managing a Wordpress website for a project. There it is required to add 300+ pages to the website.

Doing this with the FE-editor would be very redundant. That's why I'm exploring more efficient ways in doing this. Is it possible and feasible to do this with a DML? I still need to check with the technical team the DB structure of the tables.

Does anyone has knowledge about this?

Thanks
KR
Bart